# Easiest way to add new text (html) to specific line (line 101) of another html file in Command Line (Windows)

Tags: html, windows, installation, command

I'm working on a web based app. I'm a beginner so I rather stick to some of the basic codes I know for now. I want to setup individual modules or plugins that users can download with the help of a free setup/install maker that will more or less add features to my web app. But in order to do that I would need to modify some html code in the program file directory to reflect (Update) the installation of the new plugin or module.

Simple HTML code works for me. Such as a simple html link tag to point to the new navbar menu option with a link pointing to the new installed module or plugin. Again sounds simple I would think.

But in this setup file I need something that will tell the install program to modify C:\Program Files\Myapp\menu.html append html link tag to line 101 to reflect this small change.  And save it without deleting the other lines of html code.

I thought the simplest way is with the command prompt. This seems to kind of work:

```
ren test.html temp.txt
echo.new first line>temp.txt
type temp.txt >>test.html
del temp.txt
```

But this ads the new entry to the start of the file and this would break my  tag all together.

So I'm asking if anyone knows of the command line option of some free command line app that will let me do this that I can bundle into some setup app builder with a bat to exe file creator or something. I know there could be a few options and I am asking for what ever you know could work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly answering your original question.  Instead, I'm answer this question: "Easiest way to add new text (html) to specific line (line 101) of another html file in Command Line (Windows) **that can later be modified with ease while maintaining a considerable level of flexibility** "

Starting with this example text in a file:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
Line9
```

The following code:

1. Was placed in a file ending with the extension ".CMD".
2. Had a file of the above contents drag-n-dropped on it from Windows Explorer.
3. Started execution by enabling delayed expansion of variables (see code for examples where !VarName! was used).
4. Uses GOTO to skip over the InsertLines function.
5. Sets "InsertAt" variable to 5.
6. Uses "FOR" to loop through the file(s) that were/was dropped onto this file at time of execution, processing each one at a time.  (Yes, you can select more than one file, drag them all, and drop them all onto this file to have each processed.)
7. Renames each file to a temporary file name of "New.Temporary.File.Name.*"
8. Then uses an inner "FOR" to loop through each line of the file currently being processed, while maintaining the line number in the variable "LineNumber".  **BE AWARE** of the fact that this inner "FOR" uses "USEBACKQ" so files enclosed in quotes can be uses, disables "EOL" by setting it to the same value of "DELIMS", and in theory, disables "DELIMS" by setting "TOKENS" to "*". This **SHOULD** prevent "FOR" from ending lines on "~" or splitting on "~", but I would advise always trying to use a character for "EOL" and "DELIMS" that isn't found in a file.  Why? This particular flavor of the "FOR" command has a bad, and well deserved, reputation for nasty surprises.  But properly controlled use should be safe.
9. Checking each line to see if it's line number matches variable "InstertAt" variable, and when it does, it calls "InsertLines" passing the name of the file that the lines are to be inserted into.
10. And cleans up by deleting the original file that had earlier been renamed.

```
@ECHO OFF
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
GOTO :Start

:InsertLines
    (
        ECHO;Inserted Line 1
        ECHO;Inserted Line 2
        ECHO;Inserted Line 3
    ) >>%1
GOTO :EOF

:Start
    SET InsertAt=5
    FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
        SET TempRenFile=New.Temporary.File.Name%%~xA
        DEL "!TempRenFile!" 2>NUL
        REN %%A "!TempRenFile!"
        SET LineNumber=1
        FOR /F "USEBACKQ EOL=~ TOKENS=* DELIMS=~" %%L IN ("%%~dpA!TempRenFile!") DO (
            IF !LineNumber! EQU %InsertAt% CALL :InsertLines %%A
            ECHO;%%L>>%%A
            SET /A LineNumber+=1
        )
        DEL "!TempRenFile!" 2>NUL
    )
```

When the above described drag-n-drop of the file was done, its content now looks as follows.  As you can see, the line where "Line5" should have been, now has "Inserted Line 1", with "Line5" now moved down to line 8.

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Inserted Line 1
Inserted Line 2
Inserted Line 3
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
Line9
```

**NOTE:**
With enabling of delayed expansion of variables, variables inside parentheses act as follows: Variables enclosed in exclamation marks (!VarName!) return the current value of the variable, but variables enclosed in percent signs (%VarName%) return the value the variable had at the time execution entered the parentheses.  This behavior can be useful such as restoring a variables value just before execution exits the parentheses.

**ALSO NOTE:** Function "InsertLines" can be anything you want as long as it appends to current file passed to it.  So you could just append another file instead of echoing text.

**AND ALSO:** The trigger to call "InsertLines" does NOT have to be a line number.  You could be checking for a line with certain text in it.  Simplest way to do that would be to save the line to a variable, then check if removing the text you are looking for has changed the content of that variable, for example, something like this:

```
            SET ThisLine=%%L
            IF "!ThisLine!" NEQ "!ThisLine:7=!" CALL :InsertLines %%A
```

When the above 2 lines of code replace the line `IF !LineNumber! EQU %InsertAt% CALL :InsertLines %%A`, it results in text being inserted prior to line 7 because the text in that line ("Line7") has a "7" in it, and the "IF" statement's right side of "NEQ" had removed the "7" from "ThisLine".  The resulting text file is as follows:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Inserted Line 1
Inserted Line 2
Inserted Line 3
Line7
Line8
Line9
```